# simplify Boolean function F(A, B, C, D) = ∑ m(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7,8,9 11, 13,14,15)

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Hello just got stuck simplifying this boolean function using four variable K-Map.
I have to simplify this boolean function in terms of sum of minterms.

```
F(A, B, C, D) = ∑m(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15)
```

I got two answers from simplifying. I want to know if both can be correct?

Solution A:

[image: First solution diagram]

I am getting `A'C' + D + ABC + AB'C'`

Solution B:

[image: Second Solution]

I am getting `A'C' + D + ABC + B'C'D'`

Is my both solutions applicable?
I am asking this because I have doubt in solution B. According to rule adjacent boxes can be combined,and adjacent boxes differ by just one variable(or say literal). Can I combine `m8` with `m0` instead of combining it with `m9`?

Of course the 4 variable K map template is
[image: K map]

Comment: why do you have a doubt in solution B?

Answer (score 1):

Every minterm should be covered by the largest possible power of two area:
[image]

Which gives the final expression:

```
A'C' + B'C' + D + ABC
```